# Can PHP cache extension affect images quality?

Tags: php

I'm using `Invision Power Board 4.2 CMS`, some days ago I've noticed, that my images quality got worse. And.. Some days ago I've tried to install `APCu` || `memcached` extensions. So, can these extensions cause poor image quality? Because these extensions removed all whitespaces and new lines from html code. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

apcu/memcached php extensions has nothing to do with image quality. And they also has nothing to do with html whitespace. It's probably done by something else in the application code/webserver/proxy.

Maybe you enabled some caching or optimization features in the application, or added cdn?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Yep, I'm using cloudflare cdn